# .NET LINQ query syntax vs method chain

Tags: .net, linq, performance

Is there any performance difference between the following two statements?

```
from item in collection 
where item.id == 3
select item
```

and

```
collection.Where(item => item.id ==3)
```

In general, is there any performance difference between the LINQ syntax and the method chain?

Comment: More correctly it is "comprehension expression", and "fluent interface" (in the former case because the C# query syntax is not tied to LINQ, and in the latter because that's what method chaining is generally called).

Answer (score 57, accepted):

No, because they are compiled into *exactly* the same code.

Basically query expressions are "pre-processed" by the compiler into "C# 3 without query expressions" and then the rules of overloading, lambda expression translation etc are applied as normal. It's a really elegant system which means that the rules for query expressions are limited to just one small bit of the spec.

Of course, there are various things you can write in "chained method" syntax which can't be written in query expression syntax, either due to using other overloads or the methods simply not being supported (e.g. `Count()`) - but unless you're using those, the compiled code will be exactly the same. Pick the most readable alternative for any particular scenario.

Comment: For completeness, given that the question relates to performance, it may be prudent to mention that there may be minor differences in *compilation* times between the two alternatives;  the second alternative will probably be faster.

Comment: @Ani: In my experience, questions about performance are very *very* rarely about compilation speed. I'd expect the OP to *explicitly* specify that if that's what he meant. I think it's reasonable to assume that "performance" means "performance at execution time" unless otherwise stated.

Comment: I agree. Was only for completeness.

Comment: @JonSkeet - Just out of curiosity, do you have a preference between which to use?

Comment: @TravisJ: Whichever is simplest for the particular situation. I like query expressions for joins and groupings - anything which would introduce a transparent identifier - but for more straightforward queries I like straight method invocations.

Comment: Does that mean the query syntax will take longer time to compile?

Comment: @OgrishMan: I doubt that you'd ever notice it - I haven't written any tests for that, but I'd be astonished if it were ever significant.