# How can I set the default values in a ComboBox multicolumns?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, combobox, multiple-columns

I have a multi columns combobox. After combo population, I try to set the default values, but I get this error message

**Object reference not set to an instance of an object.**

This my code

Property

> ```
> public ObservableCollection<Model_Sedi> Sedi { get; set; }
> private Model_Sedi _Sedi_Search;
> public Model_Sedi Sedi_Search {
> get { return _Sedi_Search; }
> set {
>     _Sedi_Search = value;
>     OnPropertyChanged("Sedi_Search");
>     }
>     }
> ```

this is XAML

```
  <ComboBox x:Name="Cmb_Sede"                    
        ItemsSource="{Binding Sedi, Mode=TwoWay}"
                      SelectedValuePath="Value"
                      SelectedItem="{Binding Sedi_Search, Mode=TwoWay}" 

                      VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="189">
        <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding IdSede, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"></TextBlock>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Sede, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Padding="10,0,0,0"></TextBlock>
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
        <ComboBox.Effect>
            <DropShadowEffect Color="#FF0A0A0A" Opacity="0.6"/>
        </ComboBox.Effect>
    </ComboBox>
```

Now, how can I set the default values ? (like this doesn't work)

```
Sedi_Search.Sede = "ABC"
Sedi_Search.IdSede = 111
```

Comment: Please don't yell IN ALL CAPS; this is a professional Q&A site, not kindergarten. Also, the word you're looking for is "default", spelled with a "t" at the end.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your valuable observation.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the `Sedi_Search` property to a matching object from the `Sedi` collection. Just use LINQ for this:

```
Sedi_Search = Sedi.SingleOrDefault(x => x.Sede == "ABC" && x.InSede == 111);
```

Another way of writing this:

```
Func<Model_Sedi, bool> isMatch = delegate(Model_Sedi x)
{
    return x.Sede == "ABC" && x.InSede == 111;
};

Sedi_Search = Sedi.SingleOrDefault(isMatch);
```

The first version is just a shorthand version of the second. `x` is just a variable name used by the delegate/lambda expression. This SO question might prove useful: [Linq and lambda expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11344019/linq-and-lambda-expression).

Comment: Hi Steven.. but wath's   "x" ??

Comment: `x` is just a variable name used by the lambda expression. See the edit to my answer for clarification.

Answer (score 0):

Change `SelectedValuePath="IdSede"` in XAML and in View Model you have to do what [Steven Rands is saying.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27988731/1011959)

Comment: I have change SelectedValuePath with "IdSede", using LINQ, but Sedi_Search is always Nothing

Comment: @Alan392: And do what Steven says.