# Performance differences between different LINQ syntaxes

Tags: linq

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [.NET LINQ query syntax vs method chain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3776577/net-linq-query-syntax-vs-method-chain)

Are there any performance differences between writing a LINQ statement like this:

```
var result = (
from u in Users 
where u.Searchable.Contains(searchString) 
select u);
```

vs. like this:

```
var result = 
Users.Where(u=>u.Searchable.Contains(searchString));
```

Comment: No, both are compiled to the same.

Comment: There are programs, such as http://www.linqpad.net/ that will show you what SQL is generated from the queries you build

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no performance difference as the first query is just syntactic sugar for the second one.