# Linq Query syntax vs. Method Chain: return type

Tags: c#, linq

Reading [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/214500/linq-fluent-and-query-expression-is-there-any-benefits-of-one-over-other) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3776577/net-linq-query-syntax-vs-method-chain), I understand query syntax and method extensions are pretty much a syntactic difference. But now, I've a data structure containing measurement data and want determine percentile. I write:

```
var ds = (from device in dataSet.devices
          where !device.paramValues[i].Equals(double.NaN)
          select device.paramValues[i]).OrderBy(val => val);
double median = percentile(ds as IOrderedEnumerable<double>, 0.5);
```

and all works fine. ds is of type `System.Linq.OrderedEnumerable<double,double>`

What confuses me is to write the whole thing in query syntax:

```
var ds = (from device in dataSet.devices
          where !device.paramValues[i].Equals(double.NaN)
          orderby device.paramValues[i]
          select device.paramValues[i]);
double median = percentile(ds as IOrderedEnumerable<double>, 0.5);
```

Now, ds is of type `System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectEnumerableIterator<Dataset.DeviceData,double>` and the call to the percentile function fails.

Not sure yet what I'm missing here... - there is no praticular reason why I'd prefer the second syntax, but I'd like to understand the difference ... Thanks for your help!

Comment: It's not exactly the same code (no DataSet) but it works http://share.linqpad.net/kn55tw.linq

Comment: @Peri - thx; the point is that `percentile` expects an IOrderedEnumerable. With an IEnumerable, I confirm it works here too ...

Comment: Why does `percentile` need to know that the parameter is an `IOrderedEnumerable`? By and large, Linq is structured so that sort of coupling is unnecessary. In fact, the only method unique to `IOrderedEnumerable` that I can see in the documentation is `CreateOrderedEnumerable`, the functionality of which can be achieved with the extension methods `ThenBy` and/or `ThenByDescending`.

Comment: @BrianS by giving `percentile` that signature, we tell callers that the the method requires a sorted sequence, so it's up to the caller to provide one; and callers can also reasonably suppose that the method will not reorder its input.

Comment: @BrianS, I decided to provide sorted input to percentile, because I want to calculate multiple percentiles (eg. to create a box plot); hence it would be a waste to resort every time.

Comment: @Stefan_E: It still works - http://share.linqpad.net/hkrts9.linq

Comment: @Peri - you seem to be saved by the compiler optimization; you don't use the parameter inside the function percentile... if I change to `Console.WriteLine("It Works" + list.ElementAt(0));` I get an exception here ...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
from device in dataSet.devices
where !device.paramValues[i].Equals(double.NaN)
select device.paramValues[i]
```

is transformed into methods as follows:

```
dataSet.devices
       .Where(device => !device.paramValues[i].Equals(double.NaN))
       .Select(device => device.paramValues[i]);
```

Adding your `OrderBy` call you get

```
dataSet.devices
       .Where(device => !device.paramValues[i].Equals(double.NaN))
       .Select(device => device.paramValues[i])
       .OrderBy(val => val);
```

The other query

```
from device in dataSet.devices
where !device.paramValues[i].Equals(double.NaN)
orderby device.paramValues[i]
select device.paramValues[i];
```

is transformed to

```
dataSet.devices
       .Where(device => !device.paramValues[i].Equals(double.NaN))
       .OrderBy(device => device.paramValues[i])
       .Select(device => device.paramValues[i]);
```

As you can see, it's not exactly the same method chain, and that's because you get different object as a result. Content is the same, but the type returned is not.

Answer (score 2):

Look at the other answer first. Here is how you do the same with query syntax:

```
from device in dataSet.devices
where !device.paramValues[i].Equals(double.NaN)
select device.paramValues[i] into x //into syntax
orderby x
select x;
```