# Can a method chain be called LINQ?

Tags: c#, linq

Is it correct to call this code snippet LINQ (Language Integrated **Query**)?

```
var lstMyStrings = new List<string>();
lstMyStrings.Where(aX => string.IsNullOrEmpty(aX))
            .Skip(3)
            .ToList();
```

I am confused because **`System.Linq` is mandatory** for this code.
However, when I see questions and answer's like this: [.NET LINQ query syntax vs method chain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3776577/net-linq-query-syntax-vs-method-chain)
, then they're talking explicit about a method chain and not LINQ.

Comment: It is still LINQ, just isn't "query syntax".

Comment: @Kobi Thank you!

Comment: Linq is just a bunch of methods that work on collections of items similar to a query-based language such as SQL. Both, the query syntax and the method-chains you´ve provided are actually linq-methods from that namespace, they only differ in the syntax, not in the behavior.

Comment: @HimBromBeere Thank you for detailed clarification!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

LINQ can be written in two different ways.
One is by writing a query using LINQ declarative query syntax:

```
var query = from x in source
            where condition
            select x.Property
```

And the other is by using LINQ's extension methods:

```
var query = source.Where(condition).Select(x => x.Property);
```

Both queries are identical and will produce the same result (well, compiler error in this over-simplified example but it's the thought that counts :-))

The c# compiler translates the query into method calls.
This means that everything you write as a query can be also written using method chains. Please note, however, that the opposite is false - Some queries can only be written using Linq's extension methods.

For further reading, [here's what Microsoft have to say about it.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/query-syntax-and-method-syntax-in-linq)

Note the second paragraph starts with this:

> Query syntax and method syntax are semantically identical, but many people find query syntax simpler and easier to read.

btw, if it was'nt already clear, the reason that `System.Linq` is mandatory for the method chaining syntax also is because the linq extension methods belongs to this namespace.