# Convert lambda expression into linq c#

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

I have List of students and List of lecturers and I wrote code with double foreach statements.

Is there any way of simplifying this code using Lambda expressions?

```
public void GetLecturersWorkloadStatistics(List<Student> studentList, List<Lecturer> lecturerList)
{
    foreach (Lecturer lecturer in lecturerList)
    {
        foreach (Student student in studentList)
        {
            if (lecturer.ModuleName == student.ModuleName && lecturer.LastName == student.LecturerLastName &&
                lecturer.FirstName == student.LecturerFirstName)
            {
                lecturer.Credits = lecturer.Credits + lecturer.ModuleValueInCredits;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: are you asking how to translate this code into query syntax?

Comment: [It already **is** linq...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46070567/can-a-method-chain-be-called-linq/46070703#46070703)

Comment: *= new List<Student>();* is useless. You are re-assigning it two lines below.

Comment: Not only is that code already linq, but if you meant you wanted it written using query syntax, query syntax uses lambdas as well.

Comment: You also shouldn't call a variable `linkedList` when it's not a `LinkedList<T>` (it's a `List<T>`).

Comment: @Servy They (the lambdas) are "hidden" in the query syntax :-) As we say in Italy, "Occhio non vede, cuore non duole" (Eye doesn't see, heart doesn't ache)

Comment: BTW, that code will blow up if `text` doesn't have a space in it...(`IndexOutOfRangeException`)

Comment: And your condition is missing parenthesis to separate the `&&` and the `||`...

Comment: @Aominè Yes, I added my try, but it doesnt work.

Comment: @Rufus L it won't there is an exception before that method.

Comment: It's a public method, anyone can call it.

Comment: Can you give us the structure of `Student` ?

Comment: @ja72     public string ModuleName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string Group { get; set; }
    public string LecturerFirstName { get; set; }
    public string LecturerLastName { get; set; }
    public int Credits { get; set; }

Comment: @JustGalgaldas - not in the comments!!! edit the question to add this information.

Comment: @ja72 Sorry, fixed.

Answer (score 2):

I think the example you're trying doesn't work because it's returning an `IEnumerable<Student>` and your method is supposed to return a `List<Student>`;

You're also missing some parenthesis needed to group your `&&` clauses together, so they're separated by the `||` operator.

One way to solve this would be to change the return type of your method to `IEnumerable<Student>`, and to add some parenthesis around your `&&` clauses:

```
public IEnumerable<Student> GetStudentBySelectedLecturer(List<Student> linkedList,
    string text)
{
    var lecturerInformation = text.Split(' ');

    return from stud in linkedList
        where (stud.LecturerFirstName == lecturerInformation[0] &&
                stud.LecturerLastName == lecturerInformation[1]) ||
                (stud.LecturerFirstName == lecturerInformation[1] &&
                stud.LecturerLastName == lecturerInformation[0])
        select stud;
}
```

Another way would be to cast the return value to a `List<Student>`:

```
public List<Student> GetStudentBySelectedLecturer(List<Student> linkedList,
    string text)
{
    var lecturerInformation = text.Split(' ');

    return (from stud in linkedList
        where (stud.LecturerFirstName == lecturerInformation[0] &&
               stud.LecturerLastName == lecturerInformation[1]) ||
              (stud.LecturerFirstName == lecturerInformation[1] &&
               stud.LecturerLastName == lecturerInformation[0])
        select stud).ToList();
}
```

Of course there are still some potential problems, like if either `linkedList` or `lecturer` is `null`, or if there is no space in `text` (you would get an `IndexOutOfRangeException` when trying to access index `1`). Also, you can use the `Contains` method on the array of lecturer names to simplify your `where` condition:

You could address these by doing something like:

```
public IEnumerable<Student> GetStudentBySelectedLecturer(List<Student> students,
    string lecturer)
{
    if (students == null || lecturer == null) return null;

    var lecturerName = lecturer.Split(' ');

    return from student in students
        where lecturerName.Contains(student.LecturerFirstName) &&
              lecturerName.Contains(student.LecturerLastName)
        select student;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the exact same output of your issue, only using lambda expressions.

```
    studentListBySelectedLecturer = (from stud in linkedList
              where stud.LecturerFirstName == lecturerInformation[0] &&
              stud.LecturerLastName == lecturerInformation[1] ||
              stud.LecturerFirstName == lecturerInformation[1] &&
              stud.LecturerLastName == lecturerInformation[0]
              select stud).ToList();

    return studentListBySelectedLecturer;
```