# LINQ to SQL - Am I fetching or manipulating local data?

Tags: c#, sql, linq, linq-to-sql

On some code I have right now we are executing our LINQ to SQL queries like so:

```
db.Customers.Where(c => c.Name.StartsWith("A"))
.OrderBy(c => c.Name).Select(c => c.Name.ToUpper());
```

But a lot of examples I see, the Linq to SQL code is written like:

```
var query =
   from c in db.Customers
   where c.Name.StartsWith ("A")
   orderby c.Name
   select c.Name.ToUpper();
```

I am worried that we are fetching the whole table in the current code, and afterwards manipulating it locally, which from my point of view is not efficient compared to having the SQL server doing it.

Is the two examples equivalent or is there a difference?

Comment: both are equivalent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After finding out that what I was searching for was called "linq vs. method chaining", I found my answer here:

[.NET LINQ query syntax vs method chain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3776577/net-linq-query-syntax-vs-method-chain)

The question is whether there's a difference between method chaining and linq query, as I have described in my question.

The answer is that there is *none*, you are free to use both methods. Comments mention there might be minor differences in the compilation time, but this is not my concern.

Comment: You should describe the link since the link might die one day

Answer (score 0):

This might be superfluous information, but in both code blocks you are not going to get anything from the database. At this point, you will only have told LINQ what query it *should* run. To actually run the query you're going to need to add a call to .First, .FirstOrDefault, .Single, .SingleOrDefault, .ToList, or their async counterparts.